# What does "Missing value on line X of /var/cache/cups/jobs.cache" mean?

Tags: cups

When I do sudo cupsd -t I get the following error:

```
Missing value on line 238 of /var/cache/cups/jobs.cache
Missing value on line 3282 of /var/cache/cups/jobs.cache
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the "missing value" lines mean, but I got this when attempting to print with Ubuntu 18.04 and print jobs would awaken the printer but then disappear. To solve it I had to delete the printer and add it again.

Comment: Does not explain what the error means.